# Problem in setting initial position using SharedObject

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have created a simple audio player to play continuously even if the
   page is refresh it will play continuously.

**This is my code to store audio position in flash Temp memory**

```
MySharedObject.data.audioPos = mySndChannel.position;
MySharedObject.flush();
```

**MyProblem**
     When the player starts the sndPosition is null, so it was not playing. If I set some value, when I am refreshing it will not continue from the last position. How can I set the initial position to play from the start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MySharedObject.data.audioPos = mySNDChannel.position ? mySNDChannel.position : 0;
```

If `mySNDChannel.position == null`, this will set `audioPos` to 0. If it's not null, it will assign it to `audioPos`.

I haven't done anything like this, but this solution makes sense in my mind. If this isn't acceptable/correct, let me know and I'll look into the flash temp memory a bit deeper.

Comment: I tried this... but I have used mySNDChannel.position == ''. Thanks.